How do I arrange a Nuget packages folder?
I have set my Nuget packages folder using nuget.config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="/home/abc/scratch/packages" />
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="/home/abc/scratch/packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>

I can verify this with:
$ dotnet nuget locals all --list
http-cache: /home/abc/.local/share/NuGet/http-cache
global-packages: /home/abc/scratch/packages
temp: /tmp/NuGetScratchabc
plugins-cache: /home/abc/.local/share/NuGet/plugin-cache

Now I want to download a package from Nuget and use it in a project:
wget https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.3

This will download a zip file containing the DLLs etc.
How should I arrange this in the packages folder so that dotnet can find it?
(Yes I am aware of dotnet add package ... but for various reasons I want to work from a particular folder. Please take this as given!)

Just to be sure - have you tried just putting it in one of the folders?

Yes - it didn't find it so I assumed I had named it incorrectly or similar.

Just downloading the package is not enough AFAIK.
Did you try to also extract it in the expected place?
mkdir -p /home/abc/scratch/packages/newtonsoft.json/13.0.3
cd /home/abc/scratch/packages/newtonsoft.json/13.0.3
wget https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.3 -O newtonsoft.json.13.0.3.nupkg
unzip newtonsoft.json.13.0.3.nupkg -d /home/abc/scratch/packages/newtonsoft.json/13.0.3

